# JComboBox in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane, jcombobox

i have many JComboBoxes that i add in a Panel with a BoxLayout. 
All works fine large Text will be wrapped in two or three Lines, that is why i am using the html Tags.

My problem is, when there are sooo many Checkboxes i will add a ScrollPane. The ScrollPane should only use "VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED" but this will break the format from the text to only one line.

Edit:
The question is, how i can add the panel in the JScrollPane with linebreaks in the Combobox text. With the scrollpane it doesnt work.

Here is a simple Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MySwingTest();
}

private MySwingTest(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private Component createCenterPanel() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10;i++){
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("<html>das das das das das da d da fdfsdf dfsd fsdfsdf sdfsd fsdfsd fsdf fsd fss fs </html>"));
    }
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    return pane;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is, how i can add the panel in the JScrollPane with linebreaks in the Combobox text. With the scrollpane it doesnt work. There is only one line and the "other" text disappears.

Comment: Apply <br/> at the middle of CheckBox text.

Comment: will be fine if you post the image how it should seem like.

Comment: @Masud you mean <br></br>

Comment: There is only one line. The text goes out of the panel and disappears. The <br> is a option but the text will typed from the user. Its only a example. The break should be automatic like without the scrollpane.

Comment: Had you see my last post? The problem is that i dont know the text in the box the user can change it. Without the scrollpane the linebreak works automatic that the end of the box. With the scrollpane there is only one line for the box. That is why i need an automatic break or i must calculate the <br/>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want, if I understand you correctly, is a panel that is never wider than the JScrollPane that contains it.  Swing has an interface, [Scrollable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html), specifically intended for this purpose:

```
class CheckboxPanel
extends JPanel
implements Scrollable {
    private final int checkBoxHeight;

    public CheckboxPanel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        checkBoxHeight = new JCheckBox("Example").getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        // This prevents a horizontal scrollbar from appearing.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                          int orientation,
                                          int direction) {
        if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
            return 1;
        }

        return Math.min(checkBoxHeight, direction < 0 ?
            visibleRect.y : getHeight() - (visibleRect.y + visibleRect.height));
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                                           int orientation,
                                           int direction) {
        if (orientation == SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL) {
            return 10;
        }

        return Math.min(visibleRect.height, direction < 0 ?
            visibleRect.y : getHeight() - (visibleRect.y + visibleRect.height));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add some `addComponentListener` and set `setPreferredSize` for panel:

```
public class MySwingTest {

    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MySwingTest();
    }

    private MySwingTest(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createCenterPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Component createCenterPanel() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10;i++){
            panel.add(new JCheckBox("<html>das das das das das da d da fdfsdf dfsd fsdfsdf sdfsd fsdfsd fsdf fsd fss fs </html>"));
        }   

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);   

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

          scrollPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {   
             @Override
             public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {              
                Rectangle rect = scrollPane.getViewportBorderBounds();

              panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)rect.getWidth()-10, (int)panel.getPreferredSize().getHeight()+100)); // dummy offset
             }
          });

        return scrollPane;
    }
}
```

Its not ideal what you want but direction.

Hope it will help